# .download format instead of exe

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista

I downloaded some files .exe format from ftp on my vista,windows recognized them and I installed the files,
now I downloaded the same files from same ftp on my other windows XP Professional,It downloaded the files but with .download format and same size (as i did in vista)
what shall I do so that they get downloaded in .exe format in my XP?
Cheers

Comment: Change/Rename the extension?

Comment: Why not just copy the files from Vista to XP and save the bandwidth? Would be much faster too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .download extension normally indicates an incomplete download - the file is started but not finished.

I would try to re-download from a different browser and/or into a diff folder.

Comment: I guessed so,but the files' size are completely same,
lets have a go